# Dot net 3.5: does dot net 3.5 provides some api to calculate crc32 for input data?

Tags: .net, crc32

Does dot net 3.5 provides some api to calculate crc32 for input data?I have got some links which provides source code to do so.But i want to use Dot Net Api's code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no native code do calculate CRC32, but check this out: [How do I calculate the CRC32 (Cyclic Redundancy Checksum) of a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128/how-do-i-calculate-crc32-of-a-string)