# CRC32 hex in .net

Tags: c#, vb.net, crc32

I'm trying to find a CRC32 computation algorythm that output data in positive 8-character HEX (like winrar CRC for example).

All algorythms found return a positive/negative integer that I don't know how to handle...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128/how-do-i-calculate-crc32-of-a-string) which links to [This answer](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/Calculating_CRC32_in_C_and_NET)

Comment: http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net

Comment: Already checked it out, but it returns unsigned int32. Can i convert it to HEX using .ToString("x16") ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll bet that all of the CRC32 algorithms you found return a 32-bit integer (e.g. `int` or `uint`). When you view it, you're probably viewing it as a base-10 number. By viewing I mean formatting the integer as a string without passing any format options to [`Int32.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx) or [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx).

If you were to put Visual Studio into Hexadecimal View, you would get your "expected" output. The algorithms are all correct in this case, however, it is your *expectation* that is incorrect!

Instead, use a [Number Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) which produces the string representation you desire:

```
uint crc32 = Crc32Class.GetMeAValue(data);

// For example, we'll write base-10 and base-16 the output to the console
Console.WriteLine("dec: {0}", crc32);
Console.WriteLine("hex: {0:X8}", crc32);
```

Comment: Just let me understand: why X8 and not X16?

Comment: @Teejay: there are 4-bits to a base-16 "digit" (hexit?) and 32-bits in a 32-bit integer, so: `(32 / 4) == 8`.

Comment: Thank you one more time. So, assuming a Int16, I have to use "x4" ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to understand an argument that specifies the base? Something like tostring(16)

Comment: No. If I have a Int32 as soruce value, the toString(16) would automatically do a toString("x8"), the toString(2) would automatically do a toString("x32"). Same way, if my source is a Int16, toString(16) would do a toString("x4") etc...

Comment: Same broad range of outputs, lower complexity. Incidentally, a lot of programming languages support this way to operate base conversion.

Comment: Actually "X" means convert to HEX, and 8 is the padding wanted. Please edit your comment to avoid confusion to other users