# Calculate CRC32 of an String or Byte Array

Tags: vb.net, hash, crc32

Is there any function or example for VB.NET to calculate CRC32 of an string or Byte Array?

Comment: is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128/how-do-i-calculate-crc32-of-a-string) what you needed.?

Comment: Actually i looked it before,But non of them works and most of those links was for Calculating CRC32 of a file

Comment: "non of them works" Really, whats wrong with them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this:

```
Private Sub Main()
    Crc32.ComputeChecksum(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Some string")).Dump()
End Sub

Public Class Crc32
    Shared table As UInteger()

    Shared Sub New()
        Dim poly As UInteger = &Hedb88320UI
        table = New UInteger(255) {}
        Dim temp As UInteger = 0
        For i As UInteger = 0 To table.Length - 1
            temp = i
            For j As Integer = 8 To 1 Step -1
                If (temp And 1) = 1 Then
                    temp = CUInt((temp >> 1) Xor poly)
                Else
                    temp >>= 1
                End If
            Next
            table(i) = temp
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ComputeChecksum(bytes As Byte()) As UInteger
        Dim crc As UInteger = &HffffffffUI
        For i As Integer = 0 To bytes.Length - 1
            Dim index As Byte = CByte(((crc) And &Hff) Xor bytes(i))
            crc = CUInt((crc >> 8) Xor table(index))
        Next
        Return Not crc
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Helped a lot... Nice question and excellent answer.... +1 for both..

Comment: @Magnus ... what is the difference, if I use instead of `Encoding.UTF8` to  `Encoding.UTF7` or 'Encoding.UTF32`

Comment: @VenuGoPal You can find useful information about that here: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/02/difference-between-utf-8-utf-16-and-utf.html#axzz6dTQdmFYI but essentially it is how many bits it takes to represent a character. Different encodings do this differently.