# How can I calculate a CRC32 as a signed integer in C#?

Tags: c#, hash, crc32, hashalgorithm

I'm a PHP developer and a little out of my element in C#. In PHP, there's a [crc32() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) which returns a signed integer for any string that you pass in.

So this is what I'm used to:

```
<?php
echo crc32("test");
// displays -662733300
```

I would like to do the same thing in C#. I came across [this C# class library](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net) but understand little about it. According to his instructions, I'm supposed to do this:

```
// first convert string to byte-array
String input = "test";
byte[] bytes = new byte[input.length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(input.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

// then calculate the value
Crc32 crc32 = new Crc32();
String output = "";
foreach (byte b in crc32.ComputeHash(bytes))
{
    output += b.ToString("x2").ToLower();
}
```

That gives me an output string of `27d86d6a`. What do I need to do instead to return a signed integer? (Which in this example should equal `-662733300`)

Comment: Several references to .net crc calculators [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128/how-do-i-calculate-crc32-of-a-string)

Comment: @MitchWheat - not sure but AFAIK that's how PHP has always had it implemented (on 32-bit machines anyway). For my purposes I need something that will be consistent with that behavior.

Comment: from the link you posted: "Because PHP's integer type is signed many crc32 checksums will result in negative integers on 32bit platforms. On 64bit installations all crc32() results will be positive integers though. So you need to use the "%u" formatter of sprintf() or printf() to get the string representation of the unsigned crc32() checksum in decimal format."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try use [BitConverter.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var crcVal = BitConverter.ToInt32(crc32.ComputeHash(bytes), 0);
```

**EDIT**

It's seems you use different Crc32 algorithm implementation, try the following one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        // first convert string to byte-array
        String input = "test";
        byte[] bytes = new byte[input.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(input.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        // then calculate the value
        var crcVal = crc32(input);

        Console.WriteLine((int)crcVal);

    }

    public uint crc32(string input) {
        var table = new uint[]{
            0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xEE0E612C, 0x990951BA, 0x076DC419, 0x706AF48F,
                0xE963A535, 0x9E6495A3, 0x0EDB8832, 0x79DCB8A4, 0xE0D5E91E, 0x97D2D988,
                0x09B64C2B, 0x7EB17CBD, 0xE7B82D07, 0x90BF1D91, 0x1DB71064, 0x6AB020F2,
                0xF3B97148, 0x84BE41DE, 0x1ADAD47D, 0x6DDDE4EB, 0xF4D4B551, 0x83D385C7,
                0x136C9856, 0x646BA8C0, 0xFD62F97A, 0x8A65C9EC, 0x14015C4F, 0x63066CD9,
                0xFA0F3D63, 0x8D080DF5, 0x3B6E20C8, 0x4C69105E, 0xD56041E4, 0xA2677172,
                0x3C03E4D1, 0x4B04D447, 0xD20D85FD, 0xA50AB56B, 0x35B5A8FA, 0x42B2986C,
                0xDBBBC9D6, 0xACBCF940, 0x32D86CE3, 0x45DF5C75, 0xDCD60DCF, 0xABD13D59,
                0x26D930AC, 0x51DE003A, 0xC8D75180, 0xBFD06116, 0x21B4F4B5, 0x56B3C423,
                0xCFBA9599, 0xB8BDA50F, 0x2802B89E, 0x5F058808, 0xC60CD9B2, 0xB10BE924,
                0x2F6F7C87, 0x58684C11, 0xC1611DAB, 0xB6662D3D, 0x76DC4190, 0x01DB7106,
                0x98D220BC, 0xEFD5102A, 0x71B18589, 0x06B6B51F, 0x9FBFE4A5, 0xE8B8D433,
                0x7807C9A2, 0x0F00F934, 0x9609A88E, 0xE10E9818, 0x7F6A0DBB, 0x086D3D2D,
                0x91646C97, 0xE6635C01, 0x6B6B51F4, 0x1C6C6162, 0x856530D8, 0xF262004E,
                0x6C0695ED, 0x1B01A57B, 0x8208F4C1, 0xF50FC457, 0x65B0D9C6, 0x12B7E950,
                0x8BBEB8EA, 0xFCB9887C, 0x62DD1DDF, 0x15DA2D49, 0x8CD37CF3, 0xFBD44C65,
                0x4DB26158, 0x3AB551CE, 0xA3BC0074, 0xD4BB30E2, 0x4ADFA541, 0x3DD895D7,
                0xA4D1C46D, 0xD3D6F4FB, 0x4369E96A, 0x346ED9FC, 0xAD678846, 0xDA60B8D0,
                0x44042D73, 0x33031DE5, 0xAA0A4C5F, 0xDD0D7CC9, 0x5005713C, 0x270241AA,
                0xBE0B1010, 0xC90C2086, 0x5768B525, 0x206F85B3, 0xB966D409, 0xCE61E49F,
                0x5EDEF90E, 0x29D9C998, 0xB0D09822, 0xC7D7A8B4, 0x59B33D17, 0x2EB40D81,
                0xB7BD5C3B, 0xC0BA6CAD, 0xEDB88320, 0x9ABFB3B6, 0x03B6E20C, 0x74B1D29A,
                0xEAD54739, 0x9DD277AF, 0x04DB2615, 0x73DC1683, 0xE3630B12, 0x94643B84,
                0x0D6D6A3E, 0x7A6A5AA8, 0xE40ECF0B, 0x9309FF9D, 0x0A00AE27, 0x7D079EB1,
                0xF00F9344, 0x8708A3D2, 0x1E01F268, 0x6906C2FE, 0xF762575D, 0x806567CB,
                0x196C3671, 0x6E6B06E7, 0xFED41B76, 0x89D32BE0, 0x10DA7A5A, 0x67DD4ACC,
                0xF9B9DF6F, 0x8EBEEFF9, 0x17B7BE43, 0x60B08ED5, 0xD6D6A3E8, 0xA1D1937E,
                0x38D8C2C4, 0x4FDFF252, 0xD1BB67F1, 0xA6BC5767, 0x3FB506DD, 0x48B2364B,
                0xD80D2BDA, 0xAF0A1B4C, 0x36034AF6, 0x41047A60, 0xDF60EFC3, 0xA867DF55,
                0x316E8EEF, 0x4669BE79, 0xCB61B38C, 0xBC66831A, 0x256FD2A0, 0x5268E236,
                0xCC0C7795, 0xBB0B4703, 0x220216B9, 0x5505262F, 0xC5BA3BBE, 0xB2BD0B28,
                0x2BB45A92, 0x5CB36A04, 0xC2D7FFA7, 0xB5D0CF31, 0x2CD99E8B, 0x5BDEAE1D,
                0x9B64C2B0, 0xEC63F226, 0x756AA39C, 0x026D930A, 0x9C0906A9, 0xEB0E363F,
                0x72076785, 0x05005713, 0x95BF4A82, 0xE2B87A14, 0x7BB12BAE, 0x0CB61B38,
                0x92D28E9B, 0xE5D5BE0D, 0x7CDCEFB7, 0x0BDBDF21, 0x86D3D2D4, 0xF1D4E242,
                0x68DDB3F8, 0x1FDA836E, 0x81BE16CD, 0xF6B9265B, 0x6FB077E1, 0x18B74777,
                0x88085AE6, 0xFF0F6A70, 0x66063BCA, 0x11010B5C, 0x8F659EFF, 0xF862AE69,
                0x616BFFD3, 0x166CCF45, 0xA00AE278, 0xD70DD2EE, 0x4E048354, 0x3903B3C2,
                0xA7672661, 0xD06016F7, 0x4969474D, 0x3E6E77DB, 0xAED16A4A, 0xD9D65ADC,
                0x40DF0B66, 0x37D83BF0, 0xA9BCAE53, 0xDEBB9EC5, 0x47B2CF7F, 0x30B5FFE9,
                0xBDBDF21C, 0xCABAC28A, 0x53B39330, 0x24B4A3A6, 0xBAD03605, 0xCDD70693,
                0x54DE5729, 0x23D967BF, 0xB3667A2E, 0xC4614AB8, 0x5D681B02, 0x2A6F2B94,
                0xB40BBE37, 0xC30C8EA1, 0x5A05DF1B, 0x2D02EF8D
        };

        unchecked 
        {
            uint crc = (uint)(((uint)0) ^ (-1));
            var len = input.Length;
            for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
                    crc = (crc >> 8) ^ table[
                        (crc ^ (byte)input[i]) & 0xFF
                ];
            }
            crc = (uint)(crc ^ (-1));

            if (crc < 0) {
                crc += (uint)4294967296;
            }

            return crc;
        }
    }

}
```

**[Demo](http://dotnetfiddle.net/iq7seQ)**

Comment: Your code did yield an integer; however it wasn't the one I was looking for. Running that code on the string `test` returns `1785583655`, but it should give `-662733300`

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Thank you! (And by the way, I'm guessing you snagged some of that from the PHP source code?)

Comment: you can get rid of the `BlockCopy` and use `byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);` instead.

Comment: @Tony Thanks you for the implementation, but I have a problem with string with diacritics. I am working hashing words, words with diacritics have got different hash than the hash of the php implementation (crc32()), any idea of this?

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz you are right of course, I used it basically because quesion author used that. In fact my implementation doesn't need these 2 lines at all.

Comment: Sorry @dlopezgonzalez, I'm not familiar with diacritics :( Maybe there is a difference in byte representation in .Net and PHP?

Comment: @Tony Ok. I mean with diacritics, accents for example. The thing is when I do in php crc32('células') and in net crc32('células') (your implementation) I got different results, but I obtain the same hash if I use "celulas", I will check the byte representation in each platform to see whats happening.