# Different results using the crc32 function between C# and php

Tags: c#, php, crc, crc32

I have been preparing a big list of words using crc32 for hashing each word, I do this process on C# but there is a process on php, my surprise comes when I see that the crc32 function used in C# produces different hash than the standard crc32 function on PHP.

The function on C# gives an unsigned int and php gives signed int but doing `printf("%u\n", $crc_value)` you can obtaind the usigned int, however this neither match the C# value.

(I put on the bottom the C# code)

Is there a way to ajust the php function for give me the same results?

I put here hashes produces in each language:

php:

```
$value = crc32("emisiones")
//signed int => 1277409361 
//unsigned int => 1277409361
```

c#:

```
Crc32.CRC32String("emisiones");
// unsigned int => 3523227667

Crc32.CRC32Bytes(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("emisiones"));
// bytes => 101,109,105,115,105,111,110,101,115
// unsigned int => 3525485962
```

**crc32 implementation of c#:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Foo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A utility class to compute CRC32.
    /// </summary>
    public class Crc32
    {
        private uint _crc32 = 0;
        static private uint[] crc_32_tab =  // CRC polynomial 0xedb88320 
          {
        0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c, 0x990951ba, 0x076dc419, 0x706af48f,
        0xe963a535, 0x9e6495a3, 0x0edb8832, 0x79dcb8a4, 0xe0d5e91e, 0x97d2d988,
        0x09b64c2b, 0x7eb17cbd, 0xe7b82d07, 0x90bf1d91, 0x1db71064, 0x6ab020f2,
        0xf3b97148, 0x84be41de, 0x1adad47d, 0x6ddde4eb, 0xf4d4b551, 0x83d385c7,
        0x136c9856, 0x646ba8c0, 0xfd62f97a, 0x8a65c9ec, 0x14015c4f, 0x63066cd9,
        0xfa0f3d63, 0x8d080df5, 0x3b6e20c8, 0x4c69105e, 0xd56041e4, 0xa2677172,
        0x3c03e4d1, 0x4b04d447, 0xd20d85fd, 0xa50ab56b, 0x35b5a8fa, 0x42b2986c,
        0xdbbbc9d6, 0xacbcf940, 0x32d86ce3, 0x45df5c75, 0xdcd60dcf, 0xabd13d59,
        0x26d930ac, 0x51de003a, 0xc8d75180, 0xbfd06116, 0x21b4f4b5, 0x56b3c423,
        0xcfba9599, 0xb8bda50f, 0x2802b89e, 0x5f058808, 0xc60cd9b2, 0xb10be924,
        0x2f6f7c87, 0x58684c11, 0xc1611dab, 0xb6662d3d, 0x76dc4190, 0x01db7106,
        0x98d220bc, 0xefd5102a, 0x71b18589, 0x06b6b51f, 0x9fbfe4a5, 0xe8b8d433,
        0x7807c9a2, 0x0f00f934, 0x9609a88e, 0xe10e9818, 0x7f6a0dbb, 0x086d3d2d,
        0x91646c97, 0xe6635c01, 0x6b6b51f4, 0x1c6c6162, 0x856530d8, 0xf262004e,
        0x6c0695ed, 0x1b01a57b, 0x8208f4c1, 0xf50fc457, 0x65b0d9c6, 0x12b7e950,
        0x8bbeb8ea, 0xfcb9887c, 0x62dd1ddf, 0x15da2d49, 0x8cd37cf3, 0xfbd44c65,
        0x4db26158, 0x3ab551ce, 0xa3bc0074, 0xd4bb30e2, 0x4adfa541, 0x3dd895d7,
        0xa4d1c46d, 0xd3d6f4fb, 0x4369e96a, 0x346ed9fc, 0xad678846, 0xda60b8d0,
        0x44042d73, 0x33031de5, 0xaa0a4c5f, 0xdd0d7cc9, 0x5005713c, 0x270241aa,
        0xbe0b1010, 0xc90c2086, 0x5768b525, 0x206f85b3, 0xb966d409, 0xce61e49f,
        0x5edef90e, 0x29d9c998, 0xb0d09822, 0xc7d7a8b4, 0x59b33d17, 0x2eb40d81,
        0xb7bd5c3b, 0xc0ba6cad, 0xedb88320, 0x9abfb3b6, 0x03b6e20c, 0x74b1d29a,
        0xead54739, 0x9dd277af, 0x04db2615, 0x73dc1683, 0xe3630b12, 0x94643b84,
        0x0d6d6a3e, 0x7a6a5aa8, 0xe40ecf0b, 0x9309ff9d, 0x0a00ae27, 0x7d079eb1,
        0xf00f9344, 0x8708a3d2, 0x1e01f268, 0x6906c2fe, 0xf762575d, 0x806567cb,
        0x196c3671, 0x6e6b06e7, 0xfed41b76, 0x89d32be0, 0x10da7a5a, 0x67dd4acc,
        0xf9b9df6f, 0x8ebeeff9, 0x17b7be43, 0x60b08ed5, 0xd6d6a3e8, 0xa1d1937e,
        0x38d8c2c4, 0x4fdff252, 0xd1bb67f1, 0xa6bc5767, 0x3fb506dd, 0x48b2364b,
        0xd80d2bda, 0xaf0a1b4c, 0x36034af6, 0x41047a60, 0xdf60efc3, 0xa867df55,
        0x316e8eef, 0x4669be79, 0xcb61b38c, 0xbc66831a, 0x256fd2a0, 0x5268e236,
        0xcc0c7795, 0xbb0b4703, 0x220216b9, 0x5505262f, 0xc5ba3bbe, 0xb2bd0b28,
        0x2bb45a92, 0x5cb36a04, 0xc2d7ffa7, 0xb5d0cf31, 0x2cd99e8b, 0x5bdeae1d,
        0x9b64c2b0, 0xec63f226, 0x756aa39c, 0x026d930a, 0x9c0906a9, 0xeb0e363f,
        0x72076785, 0x05005713, 0x95bf4a82, 0xe2b87a14, 0x7bb12bae, 0x0cb61b38,
        0x92d28e9b, 0xe5d5be0d, 0x7cdcefb7, 0x0bdbdf21, 0x86d3d2d4, 0xf1d4e242,
        0x68ddb3f8, 0x1fda836e, 0x81be16cd, 0xf6b9265b, 0x6fb077e1, 0x18b74777,
        0x88085ae6, 0xff0f6a70, 0x66063bca, 0x11010b5c, 0x8f659eff, 0xf862ae69,
        0x616bffd3, 0x166ccf45, 0xa00ae278, 0xd70dd2ee, 0x4e048354, 0x3903b3c2,
        0xa7672661, 0xd06016f7, 0x4969474d, 0x3e6e77db, 0xaed16a4a, 0xd9d65adc,
        0x40df0b66, 0x37d83bf0, 0xa9bcae53, 0xdebb9ec5, 0x47b2cf7f, 0x30b5ffe9,
        0xbdbdf21c, 0xcabac28a, 0x53b39330, 0x24b4a3a6, 0xbad03605, 0xcdd70693,
        0x54de5729, 0x23d967bf, 0xb3667a2e, 0xc4614ab8, 0x5d681b02, 0x2a6f2b94,
        0xb40bbe37, 0xc30c8ea1, 0x5a05df1b, 0x2d02ef8d
      };

        static private uint UPDC32(byte octet, uint crc)
        {
            return (crc_32_tab[((crc) ^ ((byte)octet)) & 0xff] ^ ((crc) >> 8));
        }

        internal uint CheckSum
        {
            get
            {
                return _crc32;
            }
            set
            {
                _crc32 = value;
            }
        }

        internal uint AddToCRC32(int c)
        {
            return AddToCRC32((ushort)c);
        }

        internal uint AddToCRC32(ushort c)
        {
            byte lowByte, hiByte;
            lowByte = (byte)(c & 0x00ff);
            hiByte = (byte)(c >> 8);
            _crc32 = UPDC32(hiByte, _crc32);
            _crc32 = UPDC32(lowByte, _crc32);
            return ~_crc32;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compute a checksum for a given string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">The string to compute the checksum for.</param>
        /// <returns>The computed checksum.</returns>
        static public uint CRC32String(string text)
        {
            uint oldcrc32;
            oldcrc32 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            int len = text.Length;
            ushort uCharVal;
            byte lowByte, hiByte;

            for (int i = 0; len > 0; i++)
            {
                --len;
                uCharVal = text[len];
                unchecked
                {
                    lowByte = (byte)(uCharVal & 0x00ff);
                    hiByte = (byte)(uCharVal >> 8);
                }
                oldcrc32 = UPDC32(hiByte, oldcrc32);
                oldcrc32 = UPDC32(lowByte, oldcrc32);
            }

            return ~oldcrc32;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compute a checksum for a given array of bytes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bytes">The array of bytes to compute the checksum for.</param>
        /// <returns>The computed checksum.</returns>
        static public uint CRC32Bytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            uint oldcrc32;
            oldcrc32 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            int len = bytes.Length;

            for (int i = 0; len > 0; i++)
            {
                --len;
                oldcrc32 = UPDC32(bytes[len], oldcrc32);
            }
            return ~oldcrc32;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175917/how-can-i-calculate-a-crc32-as-a-signed-integer-in-c) SO question?

Comment: The implementation located there makes the same hash than php, I will to recalculate all the think with tha new crc32 implementation (many hours  but I have learned the rule, test before!)

Comment: Your php example is wrong. I get `1245803683` for that string from php, which is the correct CRC for that string.

Comment: @MarkAdler I am sorry, the correct word for that number is "emisiones" (not "impresiones"), I have updated the question rigth now. However, the mistmaching is still there, so I have to recalculate all my words with the c# implementation of question linked by Jeroen Heier to match the php implementation.

Comment: Please show the result of `CRC32Bytes()` in the questions, and also show a hexadecimal dump of the bytes that you are feeding to `CRC32Bytes()`. `CRC32Bytes()` does the same thing that php's `crc32()` does.

Comment: @MarkAdler See the update.

Answer (score 1):

`CRC32String()` is running two bytes per character through. If you are expecting one byte per character, as the PHP code would, then you should use `CRC32Bytes()`.

Having done that, you need to fix both of those routines. They are computing the CRC on the *reverse* of the string. (Who wrote those routines?) If you run `CRC32Bytes()` on "senoisime", then you will get 1277409361. And if you run php's `crc32()` on "senoisime", you will get 3525485962.

`CRC32String()` and `CRC32Bytes()` use `text[len]` and `bytes[len]` when they should be using `text[i]` and `bytes[i]`. `i` counts forward, but `len` counts backwards. This is clearly just someone's brain fart, since you wouldn't even *need* the variable `i` if you actually intended to compute the CRC on the reverse of the string.

Also it's a rather odd way to write the code in the first place. They should have just used the most common C-ish idiom instead: `for (i = 0; i < len; i++)`.

Comment: I have tested CRC32Bytes and I have obtained different results than CRC32String and crc32 (php). ´Crc32.CRC32Bytes(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("emisiones")) != Crc32.CRC32String("emisiones") != crc32("emisiones").

Answer (score 0):

**The output of CRC32 depends on:**

1. total **bits** of **platform** (16, 32, 64 bits system?) -> [PHP crc32(): 32 vs 64 bit OS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php)
2. used **polynom** (ISO, ECMA,...?) -> [Wikipedia: List of polynoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks)
3. **unit**/**type** of processed data
4. **order** (MSO/LSO) of processed bytes -> [Wikipedia: Endianness (LSO vs MSO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

**2 questions to consider about last 2 listed items:**

- has your input been (implicitly?) converted? UTF -> ASCII: Has the [UTF BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) been removed?
- has the byte order been kept or (implicitly?) changed? LSO -> MSO / MSO -> LSO?